# How do I extend a list by one input at a time, rather than stating the number of inputs I intend to put in first?

Tags: python, list, input

I'm trying to write a program that prompts the user to input one value and hit enter, then another and hit enter etc, and for the mean of the values to be calculated when the user hits enter without typing a value.

I've botched it so the user indicates how many values they're going to put in but can't figure out how to allow any number of values to be put in one at a time.

```
b=[]
n= int(input('how many numbers are there? '))
for i in range(n):
    b.append(float(input(' enter value: ')))

print(b)

total =sum(b)
print(total)
length=len(b)
mean= total/length
print(mean)
```

The code gives the correct answer it is just frustrating that I have to indicate how many values there are. any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to implement a while loop. A while loop will continue to loop your indented code over and over again until it either reaches a break statement or no longer meets the conditions specified in parenthesis.

In this case, I suggest doing a while(true) loop and then manually breaking out of the loop when there is no input given by the user.

```
# declare list b
b = []

# while True loop
while(True):
     # get input as a string
     num = input(' enter value: ')
     # if the length of the string of variable num is zero, do
     if(len(num) == 0):
          # break out of the while loop
          break
     else:
          # append to the list as a float
          b.append(float(num))


total = sum(b)
print(total)
mean = total/len(b)
print(mean)
```

Hope this helps! =)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do it would be to use the `iter` function with the first argument being an `input` function and the second argument being the string that will stop the iteration, which can be an empty string:

```
b = list(map(float, iter(lambda: input('enter value: '), '')))
print(b)
```

Sample input/output:

```
enter value: 2
enter value: 7
enter value: 4
enter value: 
[2.0, 7.0, 4.0]
```

Comment: I love this method! To go just a step further you can replace `list()` with `map(float, )` but that's excluding any error checking

Answer (score 1):

Use a while loop:

To further explain, when nothing is passed to input then it is a blank string which evaluates to `None` Therefore just get the input, if it has something then add it *(and maybe some other sanity checks)* otherwise stop the loop.

## Edit

Added in some checks to see if input is a number before converting to float as well as if the list is empty before doing any calculations

```
b = []

while True:
    num = input('Enter value (Press Enter to finish): ')
    if num:
        try:
            b.append(float(num))
        except ValueError:
           print("Invalid Input")
    else:
        if b:
            break
        else:
            print("No numbers to calculate yet")

total = sum(b)
length = len(b)
mean = total/length
print(f"Total: {total}\nLength: {length}\nMean: {mean}")
```

Comment: need to handle the number of input to be taken, value of n

Comment: My reading of the question was OP wanted to use a zero length input to indicate the inputs have finished, instead of using n to specify how many inputs to take

Comment: he mentioned n, so better to add n , to complete the solution

Comment: plus your solution is giving error to replicate `File "solution.py", line 13
    print(f"Total: {total}\nLength: {length)\nMean: {mean}")
         ^
SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash`

Comment: Oops, my mistake I mistyped. I fixed that

Comment: Also, I do believe OP doesn't want `n` as they say "it is just frustrating that I have to indicate how many values there are"

Comment: oh got  it, my bad

Comment: No because they say "can't figure out how to allow any number of values to be put in one at a time" and in their very description of the program does not say they want to ask for `n` here "I'm trying to write a program that prompts the user to input one value and hit enter, then another and hit enter etc" ~ "without typing a value"

Comment: but in the real case it's better to add then, otherwise, if user presses enter accidentally then result will be given which won't be desired one

Comment: As would make sense, although I was only trying to follow by OP's design, and you could just do a check to see if it's empty before breaking or after the loop

Comment: that's true, your solution is absoutrly correct, for that case just need to put a condtion

Comment: That's been done. As well as checking to see if input is a number. Now it should be pretty complete for this case

Comment: cool, `try.. except` is better choice without writing all these `if` statements

Comment: yes, I fixed haha I tested but I'm being lazy with my copy pastes

Comment: Well, unless you can find a way around all of them, as you want 2 different outputs for either invalid input vs no values

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the value the user entered is empty:

```
b=[]

done = False
while not done:
    user_input = input(' enter value: ')
    if user_input:
        b.append(float(user_input))
    else:
        done = True

print(b)

total =sum(b)
print(total)
length=len(b)
mean= total/length
print(mean)
```

Example: https://repl.it/repls/GenerousEverlastingBugs

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you could do:

```
list = []
while 1:
    k = input()
    if k=="":
        break
    else:
        list.append(k)
```

When the user inputs `""`, the loop breaks, and you can do whatever you want with your list!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a `While` loop

```
lst=[]

while True:
    answer=input('How many numbers are there?')
    if answer=="":
        break
    else:
        lst.append(int(answer))
        print(sum(lst)/len(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

use while loop to your case, I use count to have the value of n and get the fixed length up to where input needs to be added.

```
b = []
n = int(input('how many numbers are there? '))

done = False
count = 0
while not done and count != n:
      try:
            user_input = float(input('enter a number: '))
            b.append(user_input)
            count = count + 1
      except:
            print(' enter valid number ')
            count = count 

print(b)

total = sum(b)
print(total)
length = len(b)
mean = total/length
print(mean)
```